# Excel VBA - dynamically adding radio buttons

Tags: excel, vba

Am currently using this code to insert radio buttons for a checklist I have in excel, but it doesn't seem to be linking my option buttons to the cell properly. Could anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
For x = 1 to 10

With ActiveSheet
  .Range("A" & x).select

  With .OptionButtons.Add(Selection.Left, Selection.Top, Selection.Width, 
    Selection.Height)
    .Name = "OptionButton & x
    .Caption = "Yes"
  End With

  .Shapes ("OptionButton" & x).ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "Sheet1!$B$" & x
End With

Next x
```

The radio button all end up being linked to "Sheet1!$B$10" instead of "Sheet1!$B$1" & x. I've checked and they don't appear to be grouped together.

Comment: On my VBA, `.Shapes ("OptionButton" & x).ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "Sheet1!$B$" & x` is giving the following error: *The item with the specified name wasn't found*. This is due to your `.Name = "OptionButton & x` statement, which seems to be naming all radio buttons the same name, which is **OptionButton & x**, instead of something like **OptionButton1**. Maybe this is related to the issue.

Comment: Option buttons are designed to allow only one button to be pushed in a group. All these buttons are being placed into a single group and the last LinkedCell statement takes over for the group thus then all being linked to B10. I have not however discovered how to unlink the buttons and create a separate group for each. You may want to investigate using checkboxes instead.

Comment: @RetiredGeek Thank you for the checkbox suggestion. I decided to go with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you try. Option button is created to share the same result of the group. It is not possible **in the way you try**...

If you really need that, even if it looks strange to me, you can use the next workaround:

Adapt your code in this way:

```
Sub testInsertOptBut()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, x As Long
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
 For x = 1 To 10
      Set rng = sh.Range("A" & x)
      With sh.OptionButtons.aDD(rng.left, rng.top, rng.width, rng.height)
        .Name = "OptionButton" & x
        .Caption = "Yes"
        .OnAction = "SetLinkedCell"
      End With
Next x
End Sub
```

And also create the next `Sub` able to do the required pseudo link:

```
Sub SetLinkedCell()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1) = _
            CBool(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat.Value)
End Sub
```

But a form OptionButton does not have events to trigger its false value. So, in order to make some sense, the above code should be adapted to adapt the value of all the other OptionButtons and the above `Sub` would be good to be adapted in this way:

```
Sub SetLinkedCell()
    Dim optB As OptionButton
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1) = _
            CBool(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat.Value)
    Set optB = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons(Application.Caller)
    refreshOptButt optB
End Sub
```

And also create a function to change the other OptionButtons value in the pseudo linked cells:

```
Function refreshOptButt(optBut As OptionButton)
  Dim sh As Worksheet, o As OptionButton
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   For Each o In sh.OptionButtons
     If o.Name <> optBut.Name Then
        o.TopLeftCell.Offset(, 1).Value = False
     End If
   Next
End Function
```

But you maybe need check boxes instead of option buttons... Each of them can be linked to a cell:

```
Sub testInsertChkBoxes()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, x As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
  deleteChkBoxes
  For x = 1 To 10
      Set rng = sh.Range("A" & x)
      With sh.CheckBoxes.aDD(rng.left, rng.top, rng.width, rng.height)
        .Name = "chkBox" & x
        .Caption = "Yes"
        .LinkedCell = sh.Name & "!$B$" & x
      End With
 Next x
End Sub
Sub deleteChkBoxes()
   Dim sh As Shape
   For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
     If left(sh.Name, 6) = "chkBox" Then sh.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

I also created a `Sub` to delete all existing (with a specific name root), to be used at least during tesing...